# Pointer to 2D character array: declaration and initialization in one step or two steps

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I'm practicing pointer arithmetic in 2D array of characters and I have some questions.
First, a 2D array of characters can basically be defined, initialized, and printed as follows.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char str[2][3] = {"ax", "zy"};

  // print strings - array and pointer
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("str[%d]: %s\n", i, str[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*(str+%d): %s\n", i, *(str + i));
  }

  // print characters - array and pointer
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("str[%d][%d]: %c\n", i, j, str[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("*(*(str+%d)+%d): %c\n", i, j, *(*(str + i) + j));
    }
  }
}
```

There are many ways to do the same thing with pointers, and some of them are listed as follows. Some work fine, others don't.

```c
/*
[0]: both "ax" and "zy" can be printed by pointer arithmetic
[X]: unpredictable result or can't print even "a" or "ax"
[XX]: initializing one pointer with two more pointers (meaningless)
[.]: only the first string "ax" can be accessed by pointer arithmetic
*/

// 1. declaration and initialization at the same time

char *ptr         = {"ax", "zy"};                  --------------[.]
                  = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[X]
                  = (char *){"ax", "zy"}           --------------[.]
                  = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"}        --------------[XX]
                  = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}     --------------[XX]
                  = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[.]
                  = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}   --------------[.]
                  = (char **){"ax", "zy"}          --------------[.]
char *ptr[R]      = {"ax", "zy"};                  --------------[O]
                  = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[X]
                  = (char *){"ax", "zy"}           --------------[X]
                  = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"}        --------------[XX]
                  = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}     --------------[XX]
                  = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[X]
                  = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}   --------------[X]
                  = (char **){"ax", "zy"}          --------------[X]
char *ptr[R][C]   = {"ax", "zy"};                  --------------[O]
                  = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[X]
                  = (char *){"ax", "zy"}           --------------[X]
                  = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"}        --------------[XX]
                  = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}     --------------[XX]
                  = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[X]
                  = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}   --------------[X]
                  = (char **){"ax", "zy"}          --------------[X]
char (*ptr)[C]    = {"ax", "zy"};                  --------------[.]
                  = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[O]
                  = (char *){"ax", "zy"}           --------------[.]
                  = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"}        --------------[XX]
                  = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}     --------------[XX]
                  = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[.]
                  = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}   --------------[.]
                  = (char **){"ax", "zy"}          --------------[.]
char (*ptr)[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};                  --------------[.]
                  = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[O]
                  = (char *){"ax", "zy"}           --------------[?]
                  = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"}        --------------[XX]
                  = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}     --------------[XX]
                  = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[.]
                  = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}   --------------[.]
                  = (char **){"ax", "zy"}          --------------[.]
char **ptr        = {"ax", "zy"};                  --------------[?]
                  = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[.]
                  = (char *){"ax", "zy"}           --------------[.]
                  = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"}        --------------[XX]
                  = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}     --------------[XX]
                  = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"}      --------------[.]
                  = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"}   --------------[.]
                  = (char **){"ax", "zy"}          --------------[.]

// 2. declaration and initialization in two steps

char *ptr = &arr;           --------------[O]
char *ptr[R] = &arr;        --------------[XX]
char *ptr[R][C] = &arr;     --------------[XX]
char (*ptr)[C] = &arr;      --------------[O]
char (*ptr)[R][C] = &arr;   --------------[O]
char **ptr = &arr;          --------------[.]
```

I do not understand hidden mechanisms in all the cases. Especially some are more difficult.
For example, pointer in case (a) can access both "ax" and "zy", but pointer in case (B) can't.
The pointer in case (b) can only access "ax".

```
(a) `char str[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};`   
    `char (*ptr)[R][C] = &str;`           ==> can access "zy"  
(b) `char (*ptr)[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};`   ==> can't access "zy"
```

(a) Both "ax" and "zy" can be accessed by pointer arithmetic.

```c
/* diagram (my thought):
ptr -> arr == *ptr+0 -> arr[0] == *(*ptr+0) -> arr[0][0] == *(*(*ptr+0)+0)
                                               arr[0][1] == *(*(*ptr+0)+1)
                                               arr[0][2] == *(*(*ptr+0)+2)
              *ptr+1 -> arr[1] == *(*ptr+1) -> arr[1][0] == *(*(*ptr+1)+0)
                                               arr[1][1] == *(*(*ptr+1)+1)
                                               arr[1][2] == *(*(*ptr+1)+2)
*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char str[R][C]
  char(*ptr)[R][C] = &str;

  // print string
  printf("%s %s %c\n", *ptr, **ptr, ***ptr);

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*ptr+%d: %s\n", i, *ptr + i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*(*ptr+%d): %s\n", i, *(*ptr + i));
  }

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("*(*(*ptr+%d)+%d): %c\n", i, j, *(*(*ptr + i) + j));
    }
  }
}
```

(b) Only "ax" can be accessed by pointer arithmetic.

```c
/* diagram (my thought):
ptr -> ???
*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char(*ptr)[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("*ptr: %s, **ptr: %s, ***ptr: %c\n", *ptr, **ptr, ***ptr);

  // print characters
  printf("**ptr: %s\n", **ptr);

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*(*(*ptr+0)+%d): %c\n", i, *(*(*ptr + 0) + i));
  }
}
```

Any hint will help me a lot.
Thanks.

---

My code for practice is shown below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define R 2
#define C 3

int main() {
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // I. One Step                                         //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  char str[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};

  /********************************************************
  [.] char *ptr = {"ax", "zy"};
            ---   ------------
        pointer   array literal
  ********************************************************/
  char *a1p = {"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("a1p: %s\n", a1p);

  // print characters
  printf("*(a1p+0):%c, *(a1p+1): %c\n", *(a1p + 0), *(a1p + 1));

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char *ptr = (char[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
            ---   ------------------------
        pointer   compound array literal
  ********************************************************/
  char *a2p = (char[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("a2p: %s\n", a2p);

  // print characters
  printf("*(a2p+0): %c, *(a2p+1): %c\n", *(a2p + 0), *(a2p + 1));

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char *ptr = (char *){"ax", "zy"};
            ---   --------------------
        pointer   pointer

  ptr = p => a == ptr+0 -> a[0] == *(ptr+0) == 'a'
                  ptr+1 -> a[1] == *(ptr+1) == 'x'
                  ptr+2 -> a[2] == *(ptr+2) == '\0'
  ********************************************************/
  char *a3p = (char *){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("a3p: %s\n", a3p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(a3p+%d): %c\n", i, *(a3p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"};  (X)
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr = (char *p[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};  (X)
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [.] char *ptr = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};

  ptr == p => a == ptr+0 -> a[0] == *(ptr+0) == 'a'
                   ptr+1 -> a[1] == *(ptr+1) == 'x'
                   ptr+2 -> a[2] == *(ptr+2) == '\0'
  ********************************************************/
  char *a6p = (char(*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("a6p: %s\n", a6p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(a6p+%d): %c\n", i, *(a6p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char *ptr = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char *a7p = (char(*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("a7p: %s, *a7p: %c\n", a7p, *a7p);

  // print characterss
  printf("*(a7p+0): %c, *(a7p+1): %c\n", *(a7p + 0), *(a7p + 1));

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char *ptr = (char **){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char *a8p = (char **){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("a8p: %s, *a8p: %c\n", a8p, *a8p);

  // print characters
  printf("*(a8p+0): %c, *(a8p+1): %c\n", *(a8p + 0), *(a8p + 1));

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [O] char *ptr[R] = {"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char *b1p[R] = {"ax", "zy"};

  // print strings
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("b1p[%d]: %s\n", i, b1p[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*(b1p+%d): %s\n", i, *(b1p + i));
  }

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("*(*(b1p+%d)+%d): %c\n", i, j, *(*(b1p + i) + j));
    }
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R] = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  // char *b2p[2] = (char[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R] = (char *){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R] = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R] = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R] = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R] = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R] = (char **){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [O] char *ptr[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char *c1p[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};

  // print strings
  printf("c1p[0][0]: %s, c1p[0][1]: %s\n", c1p[0][0], c1p[0][1]);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*c1p[0][%d]: %c\n", i, *c1p[0][i]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R][C] = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R][C] = (char *){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R][C] = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R][C] = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R][C] = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R][C] = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R][C] = (char **){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[C] = {"ax", "zy"};
          *            **
  ptr -> a == *ptr-> a[0] == *(*ptr+0) == 'a'
                     a[1] == *(*ptr+1) == 'x'
                     a[2] == *(*ptr+2) == '\0'
  ********************************************************/
  char(*d1p)[C] = {"ax", "zy"};

  // print strings
  printf("d1p: %s, *d1p; %s\n", d1p, *d1p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(*d1p+%d): %c\n", i, *(*d1p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [O] char (*ptr)[C] = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"}
            *                 **
  ptr+0 --> a == *(ptr+0) --> a[0] == *(*(ptr+0)+0) == 'a'
                              a[1] == *(*(ptr+0)+1) == 'x'
                              a[2] == *(*(ptr+0)+2) == '\0'
  ptr+1 --> b == *(ptr+1) --> b[0] == *(*(ptr+1)+0) == 'z'
                              b[1] == *(*(ptr+1)+1) == 'y'
                              b[2] == *(*(ptr+1)+2) == '\0'
  ********************************************************/
  char(*d2p)[C] = (char[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print strings
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("d2p+%d: %s\n", i, d2p + i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*d2p+%d: %s\n", i, *(d2p + i));
  }

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("*(*(d2p+%d)+%d): %c\n", i, j, *(*(d2p + i) + j));
    }
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[C] = (char *){"ax", "zy"};
               *     **
  ptr == p --> a --> a[0]
                     a[1]
                     a[2]
  ********************************************************/
  char(*d3p)[C] = (char *){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("d3p: %s, *d3p: %s, **d3p: %c\n", d3p, *d3p, **d3p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(*d3p+%d): %c\n", i, *(*d3p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [X] char (*ptr)[C] = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"};
  one pointer      two pointers
  char (*ptr)[3] = (char *[2])
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  char (*ptr)[C] = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[C] = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};
               *     **
  ptr == p --> a --> a[0] == *(*d6p + 0) == 'a'
                     a[1] == *(*d6p + 1) == 'x'
                     a[2] == *(*d6p + 2) == '\0'
  ********************************************************/
  char(*d6p)[C] = (char(*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("d6p: %s, *d6p: %s, **d6p: %c\n", d6p, *d6p, **d6p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(*d6p+%d): %c\n", i, *(*d6p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[C] = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char(*d7p)[C] = (char(*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("d7p: %s, *d7p: %s, **d7p: %c\n", d7p, *d7p, **d7p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(*d7p+%d): %c\n", i, *(*d7p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[C] = (char **){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char(*d8p)[C] = (char **){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("d8p: %s, *d8p: %s, **d8p: %c\n", d8p, *d8p, **d8p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(*d8p+%d): %c\n", i, *(*d8p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char(*e1p)[R][C] = {"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("*e1p: %s, **e1p: %s, ***e1p: %c\n", *e1p, **e1p, ***e1p);

  // print characters
  printf("**e1p: %s\n", **e1p);

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*(*(*e1p+0)+%d): %c\n", i, *(*(*e1p + 0) + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [0] char (*ptr)[R][C] = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char(*e2p)[R][C] = (char[][3]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print strings
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*e2p+%d: %s\n", i, *e2p + i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*(*e2p+%d): %s\n", i, *(*e2p + i));
  }

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("*(*(*e2p+%d)+%d): %c\n", i, j, *(*(*e2p + i) + j));
    }
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[R][C] = (char *){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char(*e3p)[R][C] = (char *){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("e3p: %s, *e3p: %s, **e3p: %s\n", e3p, *e3p, **e3p);

  // print characters
  printf("***e3p: %c\n", ***e3p);

  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(**e3p+%d): %c\n", i, *(**e3p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [X] char (*ptr)[R][C] = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char (*ptr)[R][C] = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[R][C] = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char(*e6p)[R][C] = (char(*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("e6p: %s, *e6p: %s, **e6p: %s\n", e6p, *e6p, **e6p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(**e6p+%d): %c\n", i, *(**e6p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[R][C] = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char(*e7p)[R][C] = (char(*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("e7p: %s, *e7p: %s, **e7p: %s\n", e7p, *e7p, **e7p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(**e7p+%d): %c\n", i, *(**e7p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char (*ptr)[R][C] = (char **){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char(*e8p)[R][C] = (char **){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("e8p: %s, *e8p: %s, **e8p: %s\n", e8p, *e8p, **e8p);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(**e8p+%d): %c\n", i, *(**e8p + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [?] char **dptr = {"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char **f1p = {"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("f1p: %s, *f1p: %c\n", f1p, *f1p);

  // print characters
  printf("f1p: %c\n", *f1p);

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **ptr = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char **f2p = (char[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("f2p: %s, *f2p: %c\n", f2p, *f2p);

  // print characters
  printf("f2p: %c\n", *f2p);

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **ptr = (char *){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char **f3p = (char *){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("f3p: %s, *f3p: %c\n", f3p, *f3p);

  // print characters
  printf("f3p: %c\n", *f3p);

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [X] char **ptr = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char **ptr = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **ptr = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char **f6p = (char(*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("f6p: %s, *f6p: %c\n", f6p, *f6p);

  // print characters
  printf("f6p: %c\n", *f6p);

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **ptr = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char **f7p = (char(*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("f7p: %s, *f7p: %c\n", f7p, *f7p);

  // print characters
  printf("f7p: %c\n", *f7p);

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **ptr = (char **){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char **f8p = (char **){"ax", "zy"};

  // print string
  printf("f8p: %s, *f8p: %c\n", f8p, *f8p);

  // print characters
  printf("f8p: %c\n", *f8p);

  printf("\n");

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // II. Two Steps                                       //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /********************************************************
  [0] char *ptr = &arr;
  ********************************************************/
  char *dat = &str;

  // print string
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("dat+C*%d: %s\n", i, dat + C * i);
  }

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("*(a9p+%d*%d+%d): %c\n", i, C, j, *(dat + C * i + j));
      // "zy" was printed!
    }
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R] = &arr;
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char *ptr[R][C] = &arr;
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [O] char (*ptr)[C] = &arr;
  ********************************************************/
  char(*ddt)[C] = &str;

  // print string
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("ddt+%d: %s\n", i, ddt + i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*(ddt+%d): %s\n", i, *(ddt + i));
  }

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("*(ddt+%d)+%d: %c\n", i, j, *(*(ddt + i) + j));
    }
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [O] char (*ptr)[R][C] = &arr;
  ptr -> arr == *ptr+0 -> arr[0] == *(*ptr+0)-> arr[0][0] == *(*(*ptr+0)+0)
                                                arr[0][1] == *(*(*ptr+0)+1)
                                                arr[0][2] == *(*(*ptr+0)+2)
                *ptr+1 -> arr[1] == *(*ptr+1)-> arr[1][0] == *(*(*ptr+1)+0)
                                                arr[1][1] == *(*(*ptr+1)+1)
                                                arr[1][2] == *(*(*ptr+1)+2)
  ********************************************************/
  char(*det)[R][C] = &str;

  // print string
  printf("%s %s %c\n", *det, **det, ***det);

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*det+%d: %s\n", i, *det + i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    printf("*(*det+%d): %s\n", i, *(*det + i));
  }

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C - 1; j++) {
      printf("*(*(*det+%d)+%d): %c\n", i, j, *(*(*det + i) + j));
    }
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **dptr = &arr;
  ********************************************************/
  char **dft = &str;

  // print string
  printf("dft: %s\n", dft);

  // print characters
  printf("*dft: %c\n", *dft);

  printf("\n");

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // III. Double Pointer                                 //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **dptr = &arr;
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **dptr = &ptr; char *ptr = {"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char **d1ptr = &a1p;

  // print string
  printf("*d1ptr: %s\n", *d1ptr);

  // print character
  printf("**d1ptr: %c\n", **d1ptr);

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [] char **dptr = &ptr; char *ptr = (char [R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/
  char **d2ptr = &a2p;

  // print string
  printf("*d2ptr: %s\n", *d2ptr);

  // print character
  printf("**d2ptr: %c\n", **d2ptr);

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **dptr = &ptr; char *ptr = (char *){"ax", "zy"};
  dptr -> ptr == *(dptr+0) => a -> a[0] == **(dptr+0) == 'a'
                 *(dptr+1)      -> a[1] == **(dptr+0) == 'x'
                 *(dptr+2)      -> a[2] == **(dptr+0) == '\0'
  ********************************************************/
  char **d3ptr = &a3p;

  // print string
  printf("*d3ptr: %s\n", *d3ptr);

  // print character
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(*d3ptr+%d): %c\n", i, *(*d3ptr + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  /********************************************************
  [X] char **dptr = &ptr; char *ptr = (char *[R]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [X] char **dptr = &ptr; char *ptr = (char *[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  ********************************************************/

  /********************************************************
  [.] char **dptr = &ptr; char *ptr = (char (*)[C]){"ax", "zy"};
  dptr -> ptr == *(dptr+0) == p => a -> a[0] == *(*dptr+0) == 'a'
                 *(dptr+1)           -> a[1] == *(*dptr+1) == 'x'
                 *(dptr+2)           -> a[2] == *(*dptr+2) == '\0'
  ********************************************************/
  char **d6ptr = &a6p;

  // print string
  printf("*d6ptr: %s\n", *d6ptr);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(*d6ptr+%d): %c\n", i, *(*d6ptr + i));
  }

  /********************************************************
  [] char **dptr = &ptr; char *ptr = (char (*)[R][C]){"ax", "zy"};
  dptr == p -> a == *dptr -> a[0] == *dptr+0 -> a[0][0] == *(*dptr+0) == 'a'
                                     *dptr+1 -> a[0][1] == *(*dptr+1) == 'x'
                                     *dptr+2 -> a[0][2] == *(*dptr+2) == '\0'
  ********************************************************/
  char **d7ptr = &a7p;

  // print string
  printf("*d7ptr: %s\n", *d7ptr);

  // print characters
  for (int i = 0; i < C - 1; i++) {
    printf("*(*d7ptr+%d): %c\n", i, *(*d7ptr + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  printf("The End");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the first snippet of code, the first two loops are *exactly* the same. For any array `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`.

Comment: Regarding e.g. `char *ptr = {"ax", "zy"};` your compiler should present you with a warning that tells you why that's not working as you apparently expect. And much or the rest of the initializations shown in the second snippet will lead to *undefined behavior*